# Why do we have a sudden influx of late answers?

Tags: discussion

Have the criteria for late answers changed recently? After checking this evening there were 558 Late Answers to review.

[image]

Based on the dates of most of the answers that I reviewed, maybe this category should be temporarily renamed to the *Late Review* queue.

Comment: Only 558 ? [You were late](http://oi57.tinypic.com/2uqniti.jpg) to the party I guess... :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm going to re-post [my answer from Meta AU](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14470/158442).

---

2 hours ago, [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266696/270345) was tagged [status-completed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed):

> I would like to raise the bar for **late answers** to enter the **Late
>   Answers Review Queue** to 50 rep, which is the threshold after which
>   users gain the ability **to comment**. Here are some answers that were
>   posted by users with between 10 to 50 rep (yes, there's a little
>   selection bias to be sure. I suspect most/all of these will be 10k
>   links only by the time you're reading this. Note, all of these are
>   from the **last 5 hours.**

Quoting [the proposal by SE employee Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267080/270345):

> Raising the bar to 100 would require changing two variables at once.
>   Since that would make it harder to evaluate each individual change,
>   I'd like to try raising the reputation for getting enqueued to the
>   Late Answer reviews to 50 and reconsider upping it to 100 at some
>   point in the future.

That seems to be it.

It's definitely a bug, though. From [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue#comment866393_267080):

> Just to note, the answers should not be older than a month and the
>   current spike *should* be temporary. –  Jon Ericson♦

---

*Sigh*:

> @muru: I'm sorry about that. Thank goodness I didn't raise the limit
>   to 100. As a reminder, it's easier to clear a task from this queue
>   than many others. A single review dequeues. –  Jon Ericson♦
>
> @Sven: Reverting won't help, I'm afraid. The damage has been done. I
>   have gone over to pitch in on Server Fault as an act of penitence. – 
>   Jon Ericson♦

---

### Let's get cracking, folks.

Comment: I think I only got a reviews that were older than a month. And accepted answers as well as more than 5 upvotes. A bit of filtering would have been appropriate.

Comment: @Anthon be thankful you don't have 4000 posts to review. :P

Comment: @Anthon accepted + more than 5 votes? User should have >50 rep then. So it seems rep at the time of posting is used. Dammmmmm.

Comment: I reviewed my reviews, the most upvotes was actually four. so that would fit. Since it seems Terdon has no upper review limit of 20 as a mod, the queue might still be cleared today.

Comment: @Anthon not a chance, sorry. I may not have a software limit but I have a wetware limit and can't do all that many in one night :). The other mods should pitch in while I get some rest.

Comment: @terdon I wouldn't worry, we had 250+ reviews today alone, so this should be gone by tomorrow. If it weren't for DST I would do my next 20 right now.

Comment: @Anthon looks like you were right. All gone now, well done U&L people!

Comment: You folks must have done a really good job, and really quickly. I'm around most days but haven't seen any recent spike

Comment: Late answers, so what? I really don't know what you're so concerned about. At least a late answer to an existing old question is way better than creating 10 near-identical questions just because someone might say "Aww, this is old!"